# What is the idiomatic way of specifying a range with an invalid value?

Tags: ada

I often find that I need to specify that a variable takes a value from a range which has some sort of physical meaning (e.g., the particular core on an SoC). But I also need to be able to set it to "none", to mean "at the moment it is not holding a real core identifier". I typically use one of the two patterns given below for this, but each has disadvantages:

1. The first requires an extra (and really unnecessary) type to be defined.
2. The second requires that two fields (the value and the field defining whether the value is valid) be kept in alignment manually. This alignment cannot be checked by the compiler.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is

  --  We want to specify a Unit Identifier in the range 1 .. 10.
  --  However, sometimes we need to say that the Unit Identifier
  --  being stored is invalid.
  --
  --  The first way of doing this is to define an extended range
  --  and an Invalid Identifier.

  type Extended_Core_Identifier is new Natural range 0 .. 10;
  subtype Core_Identifier is Extended_Core_Identifier range 1 .. 10;

  Invalid_Core : constant Extended_Core_Identifier := 0;

  --  The second way is to define the range to be what we actually
  --  want and then define a Boolean to say whether the value is valid.

  type Second_Try_Identifier is new Natural range 1 .. 10;
  Identifier_Is_Valid : Boolean := False;
  Identifier1 : Extended_Core_Identifier := Invalid_Core;
  Identifier2 : Second_Try_Identifier    := 6;

begin
  if Identifier1 = Invalid_Core then
    Put_Line ("Identifier1 does not hold a real core");
  end if;

  if not Identifier_Is_Valid then
    Put_Line ("Identifier2 is not a real core");
  end if;

end Main;
```

Comment: I would probably use the "extended’ pattern - example at [ARM A.18.2(7)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-18-2.html#p7). Certainly wouldn’t use your second scheme, too easy to overlook the separate validity indication.

Comment: I suspect that the reason that a moderator closed this question was ultimately due to the vague nature of “neither is really satisfactory” in the original question.  Had the OP stated precisely why each option was unsatisfactory then focused the question solely on finding the 1 solution that eliminates those defects while still accomplishing the mandated goal, then this question wouldn't have been closed on stylistic grounds.  The Ada content of OP is a very valid Ada question had OP utilized the correct magic words.  Conceivably, OPer can overtly edit OP then have a moderator reopen it.

Comment: Let's try to reopen this question by OPer editing OP to fix the opinion basis of the OP's question:  what is unsatisfactory with the 2 options given in OP.  This is a topic for Ada to shine forth its guiding-light wisdom to the moderator who closed this question.  This question shouldn't have been closed (prematurely, even without reaching 3 down-votes) by a not-Ada-expert; its Ada wisdom should have been improved incrementally to pass S.O.'s stylistic quality controls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like to use a [variant record](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/2xrm/html/RM-3-8-1.html) in situations like this.  It allows you to specify that an ID only exists if the Valid discriminant is set to True.  It also allows Ada's strong type checking to enforce that invariant (I.E. if you try to access the ID of an invalid core, the code will raise an exception).

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Hello is

    type Core_Identifier is new Positive range 1 .. 10;

    type Core (Valid : Boolean := False) is record
        case Valid is
            when True  => ID : Core_Identifier := 1;
            when False => null;
        end case;
    end record;
    
    Invalid_Core : constant Core := (Valid => False);
    
    -- Constructing function
    function Make_Core(ID : Core_Identifier) return Core
        is (Valid => True, ID => ID);
    
    -- Various initialization methods
    Core_1 : Core := Invalid_Core;
    Core_2 : Core := (Valid => True, ID => 6);
    Core_3 : Core := Make_Core(9);
    Core_4 : Core := (Valid => False);

begin
    Put_Line("Hello, world!");
  
    if not Core_1.Valid then
        Put_Line("Core 1 invalid");
    else
        Put_Line("Core 1 ID:" & Core_1.ID'Image);
    end if;
    
    if not Core_2.Valid then
        Put_Line("Core 2 invalid");
    else
        Put_Line("Core 2 ID:" & Core_2.ID'Image);
    end if;
    
    if not Core_3.Valid then
        Put_Line("Core 3 invalid");
    else
        Put_Line("Core 3 ID:" & Core_3.ID'Image);
    end if;
    
    if not Core_4.Valid then
        Put_Line("Core 4 invalid");
    else
        Put_Line("Core 4 ID:" & Core_4.ID'Image);
    end if;
    
end Hello;
```

Comment: I wonder how many readers of the link you provide to the variant record definition know what a "drum" is in that context. It's interesting that that is being used as an example in 202x. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @ChrisHobbs Yeah, he ARG panel that makes the RM document is comprised of a lot of folks that have a variety of experience, so many of them probably remember drums,  If this ends up answering your question though, please feel free to mark it as a solution. If not, then hopefully someone can give you a much better answer in a bit.

Comment: The drum reference is present in ARM-80 (MIL-STD-1815 https://archive.org/details/mil-std-ada/mode/2up) and has been retained since. Drums were obsolete even then, but people were more likely to have heard of them.